# Laravel Call a middleware if another middleware fails

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

So I have been using Passport to handle any OAuth requests which works perfectly. However there are some scenarios where I do not need a user instance to request and API endpoint. Static lists etc. I have created a middleware for that and it works fine. And finally there are scenarios when pulling things like lists where i want to give developers the freedom to either use the Token or OAuth to post to those endpoints. And struggling on how to do that...

Anyone have any insights? I am thinking I could always call the Token middleware and then from the token middleware call the normal passport OAuth? Not really sure how i would go about doing that though.

Chaining would not work in this scenario because if one fails it would boot them out, where I want it to check for a token IF it does not exist THEN check OAuth token and follow normal behavior after that.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'token:auth:api',
```

Not seeing anywhere in the docs on how to do this. But maybe I am missing something.

Cheers

Citti

Comment: uber does this alot in their APIs - https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/products-get

Comment: IMHO I think you have to write your own middleware.

Comment: @Citti were you able to find an appropriate solution to the problem? just stumbled upon this problem myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by making another middleware. In that middleware first you call the token middleware, if that fails then call the passport OAuth middleware. I have done to authenticate token using Tymon JWT, if that fails will authenticate using Laravel Passport OAuth. Following is the handle() function of the middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    try {
        return app(\Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class)->handle($request, function ($request) use ($next) {         //JWT middleware

            return $next($request);
        });
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {

        if ($exception instanceof UnauthorizedHttpException) {
            return app(\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials::class)->handle($request, function ($request) use ($next) {
                return $next($request);
            });
        }
        throw $exception;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below handle of middleware to check for normal token and otherwise send request to another middleware for authentication. 
In api endpoint allows authorization token it can be either predefined token or an oauth token.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->is('api/*')) {
            if($request->hasHeader('authorization')){
                $bearertoken = $request->bearerToken();
                $token = $request->header('authorization');
                if(!empty($bearertoken)){
                    return app(Authenticate::class)->handle($request, function ($request) use ($next) {
                        return $next($request);
                    },'api');
                }
                if(!empty($token)){
                    $client = Client::where('secret',$token)->first();
                    if(!empty($client)){
                        return $next($request);
                    }
                }
            }
            throw new APIException("Unauthorized Access.");
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Handle method of your Middlvar, add the following code:

```
$classes = (array) MiddlewareNameResolver::resolve(
    $guard, app('router')->getMiddleware(), app('router')->getMiddlewareGroups()
);

app(\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline::class)
    ->send($request)
    ->through($classes)
    ->thenReturn();
```